# Ehcache simple search/transaction example?

Tags: java, search, transactions, memcached, ehcache

I'm trying to test the capabilities of ehcache and I believe I have it set up properly in the cache initialization which I learnt from the code samples and elsewhere online. However I haven't added search attributes yet though I don't know how to successfully conduct a search regardless of which attributes. I was hoping to see a simple example of a search conducted with any attributes. Likewise, I don't know how to use the transaction capabilities of ehcache and was hoping for a simple example of this too.

```
private static CacheManager cacheManager;
private static Ehcache ehcache;
private TransactionController transactionController;

public void initCache() throws Exception {
    Configuration managerConfigur = new Configuration();
    CacheConfiguration cacheConfigur = new CacheConfiguration("testcache1",-1).eternal(true);
    Searchable searchable = new Searchable();
    cacheConfigur.addSearchable(searchable);
    //Set attributes for search here

    cacheConfigur.transactionalMode(TransactionalMode.LOCAL);

    managerConfigur.addCache(cacheConfigur);

    cacheManager = new CacheManager(managerConfigur);
    ehcache = manager.getEhcache("testCache");


}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

umm... I know that "have you tried Google" can come across as rude, but... have you tried it? :)

Specifically, have you looked at

- http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/search#making-a-cache-searchable
- http://ehcache.org/documentation/apis/transactions#local-transactions

?

It seems that there's everything you need for "simple examples" and there's an [introductory video](http://vimeo.com/21299785) for transactions... If you have more questions after that, let us know what specifically you're looking for. Hope that helps :)